# Font for email in my ipad

Tags: ipad, email, font

How do you change the default font for email on ipad?  I can change it each time I send an email but cannot “lock” it in to the regular that I want

Comment: It would be helpful to know what iOS version is on your iPad and possibly even the model...

Comment: I don’t think its possible.  Same in Mail in MacOS.  Try another app like Outlook

Comment: @TomGewecke Outlook iOS app has very basic formatting functionality as well. I think you can only bold, italicise and underline in the Outlook iOS app. However, I think HTML formatting is slowly being brought onto Outlook app. You can paste a text with different fonts/colours from another app, but can't change it directly within Outlook iOS app.

Comment: @TomGewecke Although, if you enter a signature in Outlook iOS settings with a particular font, you could continue to write in that font below it. So theoretically, you could set the signature as a single letter in the desired font, then when composing an email, the signature will appear by default. Then just hit the return key to start a new line underneath the signature to continue writing your email in the same font. Just remember to delete the signature at the top of the email before sending the email, or just have the signature as "Dear..."